# Efficiently summing reciprocal of polynomial over primes.

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, prime-numbers, infinite-product, euler-product

For fun, I have been trying to calculate the sum of the reciprocals of the [cube-full numbers](https://oeis.org/A036966). I have managed to show that the limit is equal to $$\frac{\zeta(3)\zeta(4)\zeta(5)}{\zeta(8)\zeta(10)}\prod_{p\ \mbox{prime}}\left(1-\frac1{(p^4+1)(p^5+1)}\right)\approx1.3397841535.$$ This product converges pretty fast, because of the order $9$ polynomial $f(x)=(x^4+1)(x^5+1)$ in the numerator. By simply taking the primes up to $10^8$, I already got $64$ digits of precision. $$1.3397841535743472465991525865148860527752422497881828066630150676$$ However, this method requires exponential time to calculate more digits. I was wondering if there is a faster, or even a polynomial time algorithm to calculate more digits.

One thing I tried is to take the logarithm of the product. $$\log\left(\prod_{p\ \mbox{prime}}\left(1-\frac1{f(p)}\right)\right)=\sum_{p\ \mbox{prime}}\log\left(1-\frac1{f(p)}\right)$$ By taking the Taylor series of the natural logarithm, we get $$\log\left(1-\frac1{f(p)}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-1}{n(f(p))^n}.$$ By absolute convergence, we can interchange the sums to obtain $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-1}n\sum_{p\ \mbox{prime}}\frac1{(f(p))^n}.$$ For all $n$, of course $(f(p))^n$ is a polynomial, so the question becomes how we can efficiently sum the reciprocal of a polynomial over the primes. Is there some sort of analog for the Euler-Maclaurin formula for primes?

Comment: nice question. what a cute limit at the start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Taylor expansion of $ 1 - \frac{x^9}{(1+ x^4)(1+x^5)}$ to pull out as many zeta factors as you need

\begin{eqnarray}
&& \prod_{p} \left(1 - \frac{1}{(p^4 + 1)(p^5 + 1)} \right) \\
 &=& \prod_{p} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p^9} + \frac{1}{p^{13}} + \frac{1}{p^{14}} - \frac{1}{p^{17}} - \frac{1}{p^{18}} + O(\frac{1}{p^{{19}}}) \right) \\
&=& \prod_{p} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^9}\right) \left(1 + \frac{1}{p^{13}} + \frac{1}{p^{14}} - \frac{1}{p^{17}} - \frac{1}{p^{18}} + O(\frac{1}{p^{{19}}})\right) \\
&& \dots \\
&=& \prod_{p} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^9}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{p^{13}}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{p^{14}}\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^{17}}\right)\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^{18}}\right) \left( 1 + O(\frac{1}{p^{{19}}})\right) \\
&& \frac{\zeta(13)\zeta(14)}{\zeta(9)\zeta(26)\zeta(28)\zeta(17)\zeta(18)}\prod_{p}  \left(1 + O(\frac{1}{p^{{19}}})\right) \\
\end{eqnarray}

In general you can do this for euler products of the form $\prod_p f(p)$ where $f$ has a convergent expansion in $p^{-1}$. The convergence of the above formula can be slow, but a solution is to compute the product explicitly for primes less than some $N$, and then use the formula for the remainder, being sure to adjust the zeta functions for the missing factors.

Comment: Very interesting and powerful technique! So just to elaborate on how you would continue. For $\prod_pf(p)$ we consider the Taylor series $f(p)=1\pm kp^{-n}+O(p^{-n-1})$. Then we let $g(p)=f(p)/(1\pm p^{-n})^k$ such that $g(p)=1+O(p^{-n-1})$. Then $$\prod_pf(p)=\left(\prod_p\left(1\pm\frac1{p^n}\right)\right)^k\cdot\prod_pg(p).$$ The first product can be calculated with the Riemann zeta function. So this step reduced the problem to a new polynomial of one degree lower. By recursion we can go as low as we want.

Comment: Yes that looks right. I probably missed some conditionally on $f$ to ensure convergence. I almost certainly got this from one of Henri Cohen’s books.

Comment: See section 8.4 of this https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10904

Answer (score 1):

$$\log(1-\frac{x^{9}}{(1+x^4)(1+x^5)}) = \sum_{m\ge 0} a_m x^{9+m}$$

$$\log\prod_p (1-\frac{p^{-9}}{(1+p^{-4})(1+p^{-5})}) =\sum_p \sum_m a_m p^{-9-m}=\sum_m a_m \sum_p p^{-9-m}$$ $$=\sum_m a_m \sum_l \frac{\mu(l)}{l} \log\zeta(l(9+m)) = \sum_{n\le N}(\sum_{l|n}\frac{ a_{n/l-9} \mu(l)}{l} )\log\zeta(n)+O(2^{-N})$$

Comment: This looks promising, but I am not experienced enough to fill in the gaps. Are we supposed to calculate the terms $a_m$ from the Taylor series? Is that possible in polynomial time? And how do we know it converges for $|x|<1$? And most importantly, how do you go from the sum over $p$ to the sum over $l$? Suddenly $\mu$ and $\log\zeta$ pop up, so something must be done with inclusion exclusion and the Euler product, but this step still seems like a pretty big leap. Finally, do you have a proof that the partial sums converge exponentially in the final sum?